# Why PySpark with spark-submit throws error trying to untar --archives pyspark_venv.tar.gz

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Maybe someone can shed some light on this.

Running Pyspark job in minikube. Because it is PySpark the following two conf parameters are used:

```
spark-submit --verbose \
           --master k8s://$K8S_SERVER \
           --deploy-mode cluster \
           --name pytest \
           --py-files hdfs://$HDFS_HOST:$HDFS_PORT/minikube/codes/DSBQ.zip \
           --archives hdfs://$HDFS_HOST:$HDFS_PORT/minikube/codes/${pyspark_venv}.tar.gz#${pyspark_venv} \
```

The first file --py-files send the zipped PySpark project
The second one --archives is used to send the package dependencies created with Conda
These are the output from spark

```
Parsed arguments:
  master                  k8s://192.168.49.2:8443
  deployMode              cluster
  executorMemory          5000m
  executorCores           1
  totalExecutorCores      null
  propertiesFile          /opt/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
  driverMemory            null
  driverCores             null
  driverExtraClassPath    $SPARK_HOME/jars/*.jar
  driverExtraLibraryPath  null
  driverExtraJavaOptions  null
  supervise               false
  queue                   null
  numExecutors            2
  files                   null
  pyFiles                 hdfs://50.140.197.220:9000/minikube/codes/DSBQ.zip
  archives                hdfs://50.140.197.220:9000/minikube/codes/pyspark_venv.tar.gz#pyspark_venv
  mainClass               null
  primaryResource         hdfs://50.140.197.220:9000/minikube/codes/testpackages.py
  name                    pytest
  childArgs               []
  jars                    null
  packages                null
  packagesExclusions      null
  repositories            null
  verbose                 true
```

Trying to unpack that gz file

This is what is happening from the pod logs:

```
Unpacking an archive hdfs://50.140.197.220:9000/minikube/codes/pyspark_venv.tar.gz#pyspark_venv 
from /tmp/spark-57c6ace6-c01f-420c-ab88-0cdb9015eb92/pyspark_venv.tar.gz 
to /opt/spark/work-dir/./pyspark_venv
Exception in thread "main" ExitCodeException exitCode=2: tar: lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/tests/util/__pycache__/
test_assert_categorical_equal.cpython-37.pyc: 
Cannot open: Cannot allocate memory
```

However this works fine when I run the code in local mode as opposed to k8s!

Thanks